# How would I transform a page in-place in a PDF programmatically, e.g. with imagemagick/convert

Tags: pdf, imagemagick

I have a multi-page PDF file (7 pages), in which 1 page (page 6) must go through 2 transformations (I think):

1. It must be cropped.
2. It must be scaled.

And then it must be saved again as PDF, preserving the other pages but replacing the transformed page.

The document consists of A4 size pages. Page 6 is in landscape orientation instead of portrait and it contains what should become the portrait A4 page. It is in A5 format, vertical on the page and centred horizontally, so with equal margins of whitespace to the left and right.

Here's a bad 'drawing':

```
⎡⎺⎺⎺*****⎺⎺⎺⎤
|   *****   |
|   *****   |
⎣___*****___⎦
```

The page is outlined, but the part that I want is marked with `*`.

So I think that if I first crop the page from A4 landscape to A5 portrait by just trimming the correct amount from the left and right, then I have an A5 portrait. And then I scale up the page to A4. And then save the PDF. How would I do such a thing? The saving is probably possible with such a command: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64724127/3169029. I tried that already with a manual crop of the page (which I don't want to keep doing) and it resulted in, again, a landscape page with the content centred in A5 size, which was unexpected, just like the original file.

Losing vector graphics quality is not a problem, because the PDF doesn't contain vector graphics, but it does contain raster images, so I'd like to either work with the source density or some high density that is likely to preserve some quality.

I actually have multiple files (and I will have more in the future) that have this issue, so I prefer a programmatic way to do this. I know that imagemagick/convert can probably do this, but I'm open to use other tools/scripts that can be automated.

How would I approach such a task?

Comment: Have you tried opening the PDF document with Microsoft Word and then making changes?

Answer (score 0):

One can use the [Action Wizard](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/action-wizard-acrobat-pro.html) in Adobe Acrobat Pro/DC to transform a page in-place in a PDF programmatically. It allows batch processing.

It allows [scaling](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-discussions/adobe-dc-action-wizard-and-preflight-page-scaling/m-p/9378342) and [cropping](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-discussions/action-wizard-crop-multiple-files/td-p/10238691).

[image]

([image source](https://evermap.com/tutorial_asp_mergeviaactionwizard.asp))

Disclaimer: I work for Adobe.